# Using numeric updown to step through an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am trying to use numeric updown to move back and forth through an array which stores the scores of typing tests taken by users. I'm honestly not even sure where to begin. I wrote some code but it doesn't seem to be doing much of anything.

```
    private void testUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (testUpDown.Value = allTests[i])
        {
            prevErrorsBox = Errors.ToString();
            prevWpmBox = WPM.ToString();
        }
    }
```

As you can imagine, it doesn't do a whole lot. Should I be using a different control for this? This is being done with 3 tier design, if it matters. I will have to make this form load the values from a database as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you meaning to loop through all of the values that equal the the value of your up/down control or are you wanting your updown control to control the index to your array.

Comment: I want to loop through all of the values in the array using the numeric up down control. It's essentially just going to "get" the values stored in the database I'm connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Index of the array with the Up/Down Control making sure that you can not exceed the bounds of the Array. See if something like this works for you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] values;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        values = setValueArray();
        numericUpDown1.Maximum = values.Length - 1;
        numericUpDown1.Minimum = 0;
    }

    private string[] setValueArray()
    {
     return new string[] { "100", "90", "80", "70", "60" };
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = values[(int)((NumericUpDown)sender).Value];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not have a compiler at the moment, but I will test this when I get a chance. This makes sense.

Comment: @user1729696 You are welcome, just make sure that you set the maximum to one less than the length of the array and it should work fine.